# Finding the digits of φ in π

Tags: irrational-numbers

What are the chances of finding the digits of **φ** within **π** ?

I realize we can find irrational numbers within **π**. Even by simply shifting the decimal, we can end up with new irrational numbers, which we can say are "within **π**".
But what are the chances of finding the digits of **φ** in it? Say, could at some point the digits of **π** be identical to those of **φ** and continue in the exact same pattern from there on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your last question, the answer is that the digits cannot eventually match exactly. If they did, then there would be rational numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $\pi=a+b\varphi$.

The rest of the question is that we don't know for example whether at some point there is never again a $9$ in the remainder of the decimal expansion of $\pi$. We are not in a position to determine whether all of the digits of $\varphi$ as a subsequence can be found.

Answer (score 3):

If $\varphi$ and $\pi$ were identical from some point on they would differ by a rational number. That would make $\pi$ algebraic, so it can't happen.

It's likely that any finite sequence of digits occurs in $\pi,$ because we suspect that $\pi$ is a [normal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number).